# Prometheus alert multiple routes and receiver doesn't send one rules

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have this alert configuration and expect this behavior.

If `destination: bloom` and `severity: info` send to `slack-alert-info` - it's work

Error there. If `destination: bloom` and `severity: warning|critical` send to `slack-alert-multi` - this works with error.
Sverity: **warning** sending as expected to both Slack's channels but **critical** sending only to **default** channel.

May someone help me understand my error, please?

*Amtool gives no error.*

```
amtool config routes test --config.file=/opt/prometheus/etc/alertmanager.yml --tree --verify.receivers=slack-alert-multi severity=warning destination=bloom
Matching routes:
.
└── default-route
    └── {destination=~"^(?:bloom)$",severity=~"^(?:warning|critical)$"}  receiver: slack-alert-multi

slack-alert-multi


amtool config routes test --config.file=/opt/prometheus/etc/alertmanager.yml --tree --verify.receivers=slack-alert-multi severity=critical destination=bloom
Matching routes:
.
└── default-route
    └── {destination=~"^(?:bloom)$",severity=~"^(?:warning|critical)$"}  receiver: slack-alert-multi

slack-alert-multi
```

Alert configuration

```yaml
...
    labels:
      alerttype: infrastructure
      severity: warning
      destination: bloom
...
```

```yaml
---
global:
  resolve_timeout: 30m

route:
  group_by: [ 'alertname', 'cluster', 'severity' ]
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 30s
  repeat_interval: 300s
  receiver: 'slack'

  routes:
  - receiver: 'slack-alert-multi'
    match_re:
      destination: bloom
      severity: warning|critical
  - receiver: 'slack-alert-info'
    match_re:
      destination: bloom
      severity: info

receivers:
- name: 'slack-alert-multi'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0/B0/V2'
    channel: '#alert-upload'
    send_resolved: true
    icon_url: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462'
    title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
    text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'
  - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0/B0/J1'
    channel: '#alert-exports'
    send_resolved: true
    icon_url: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462'
    title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
    text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'

# Default receiver
- name: 'slack'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0/B0/2x'
    channel: '#aws-notification'
    send_resolved: true
    icon_url: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462'
    title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
    text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'

- name: 'slack-alert-info'
  slack_configs:
  - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0/B0/EA'
    channel: '#alert-info'
    send_resolved: true
    icon_url: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462'
    title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
    text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'

templates:
- '/opt/alertmanager_notifications.tmpl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
continue: true
```

into

```
  - receiver: 'slack-alert-info'
    match_re:
      destination: bloom
      severity: info
      continue: true
```